# Bootstrap 3 RC1 - Change navbar color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to change the [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) navbar color from the default grey to #5e00ff. The customize section of Bootstrap is not available yet - how to do it manually?

Comment: How are your files set up? Are you looking to modify the less files, or override it with your own CSS file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your CSS, add this:

```
.navbar
{
    background-color: #5e00ff;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have tried adding this in my bootstrap.css file. It doesn't work. Do I have to use a separate CSS file for this?

Comment: I would suggest adding it to a different css file (custom.css), and making sure that the new file is loaded after the bootstrap.css file so that the bootstrap style gets overriden.

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS file just add

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #5e00ff !important;
}
```

This will override the bootstrap CSS file. I'm not familiar with the location of the CSS for navbar in the bootstrap files, but an easier way would be to locate that file and change the background-color assigned to it.

Comment: Please do not add additional answers if your exact answer is already posted.

Comment: @MiroMarkarian I was under the impression that my answer was slightly different using !important to override the original CSS, but alright. I apologize. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: That's perfectly fine, but you should mention the effect/importance of adding `!important`, at least briefly. Otherwise it is not obvious how your answer is different and why one should prefer your approach.

Answer (score -1):

As an additional answer, if you are building bootstrap from sources and want to have it done without any other css modifications, navigate to the `less` folder and open up `variables.less` file.

In the line 227, change this:

```
@navbar-bg: #eee;
```

To this:

```
@navbar-bg: #5e00ff;
```

And then build. :)

Comment: I recommend against modifying the included `.less` files. You are better off creating a new `mysite.less`, `@import bootstrap` at the top and then overriding the variables as needed. This means that any updates to Bootstrap 3—of which there will be many, esp. given that this is only a Release Candidate—can be pulled down by you without having to re-write your source files. Note that you should use Twitter's [RECESS](http://twitter.github.io/recess/) tool to compile the `.less` files into a single CSS file.